# Grid into Grid Popup Editor - Passing ID parameter in sub grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I have a Grid with Employes. There is a Edit button and the edit mode is set to Popup. In the EditorTemplate of the entity I want to edit, there is another grid that has a history of Salary with a incell or inline edit mode.

Both grids uses Ajax datasources. The problem is with the inner grid binding. The controller action feeding a Json result to the ajax call requires the ID of the employe we are editing to return the appropriate Salary history. However, Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC wrapper will render some sort of template of the editor before knowing which employee we want to edit, then it will edit it when we are requesting the popup.

How can I feed the Employe ID in the Read Ajax call?

**Main Grid**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.Business.Models.EmployeDTO>().Name("EmployeGrid")
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Columns(cols =>
{
    cols.Bound(o => o.someData).Title("Some Data");
    cols.Bound(o => o.moreData).Title("More Data");
    cols.Command(o =>
    {
            o.Edit();
        o.Destroy();
    }).Title("&nbsp;");
})
.Editable(editor => editor
    .Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
    .Window(window => window.Draggable().Resizable().HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "width:700px;" })))
.Sortable()
.Filterable()
.Groupable()
.DataSource(datasource => datasource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model => model.Id(o => o.id))
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetAll", "EmployesAjax"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "EmployesAjax"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "EmployesAjax"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "EmployesAjax"))
    )
)
```

**Inner Grid** (In Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/EmployeDTO.cshtml)

```
@Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.Business.Models.SalairyDTO>().Name("SalaryGrid")
.Columns(cols =>
{
    cols.Bound(o => o.someInfo).Title("Some Info");
})
.DataSource(datasource => datasource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(o => o.id);
        model.Field(o => o.employe_id).DefaultValue(Model.id);
    })

    // NEED THE ID HERE
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetByEmployeId", "SalairyAjax", new { id = "" }))

    .Update(update => update.Action("Update", "SalairyAjax"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "SalairyAjax"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "SalairyAjax"))));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically I would suggest you to Set the AutoBind option to false of the inner Grid and use the edit event of the outer Grid to perform a read request and pass the value as additional parameter.

Here is an example:

```
function onEditOfEmployeGrid(e){
    $('#SalaryGrid').data().kendoGrid.dataSource.read({id:e.model.EmployeeID})
}
```

Comment: @Pluc were you able to solve this? I am stuck in a similar problem where I am able to read the ID from the master grid into the subgrid. However,unable to read the same value inside a `toolbar` button that I have created. Can you help?

Comment: @Sarah Usually you just use #=Id# (Razor). Looking at the date of my question, I was just starting using Kendo at that time. I'm not really sure why I haven't used this syntax. You can't use it for defaults, filters or anything strongly typed, but for route data I believe you can... Either way, that's what you'll want to use in your Toolbar. If you need more assistance, feel free to start your own question with samples! It will be easier to help :)

Comment: @Pluc The `#` did not work for me. I have posted my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27417604/kendo-grid-hierarchy-passing-id-from-master-grid). Mind taking a look? Since you have already worked on a similar one, you might be able to say what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply pass the value from the grid using addtionaldata parameter within the grid. the RouteID on the (left side) can then be referenced within the Grid Popup Editor using ViewData["RouteID"]. I hope that helps

```
     .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
         .TemplateName("busStop")
         .DisplayDeleteConfirmation(true)
         .Window(window => window.Modal(true).Resizable().Draggable())
         .AdditionalViewData(new { RouteID = Model.RouteID }))
```