# Kendo Grid hierarchy passing ID from master grid

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Hierarchial Grid where the master grid contains the `Client` details and the sub grid contains the `Point of Contacts`. I am able to pass the `Client ID` from the master grid into the sub grid `Read` action and the data is loading fine. However, the issue comes while passing the `Client ID` into a `Add New Point of Contact` button in the sub grid. If I hard-code the value the Controller method runs fine. However, it is unable to pick the reference `Client ID`.

The sub grid is as follows:

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Track24.Billing.Web.Models.ListPointOfContactViewModel>()
.Name("grid_#=ClientID#")
.Columns(columns =>
{
columns.Bound(p => p.POC_ClientID);
columns.Bound(p => p.ContactName);
columns.Bound(p => p.RegionName).Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("regionFilter"));
columns.Bound(p => p.CountryName).Filterable(filterable => filterable.UI("countryFilter"));
columns.Bound(p => p.ContactEmail);
columns.Bound(p => p.ContactNumber);
})
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Template(@<text>
<a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add subgridadd" href="@Url.Action("CreatePOC", "PointOfContact", new { id = "\\#= ClientID\\#" })"><span class="k-icon k-add"></span>Add new Point-of-Contact</a></text>))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.PageSize(10)
.Read
(
read => read.Action("ClientBinding_PointOfContacts", "PointOfContact", new { clientID = "#=ClientID#" })
)
)
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.ToClientTemplate()
)
</script>
```

The sub grid binds correctly with the master grid; hence ClientID is read properly in the sub grid. However, I am unable to read the same in the `Add New` button.

EDIT 1: This is my main (parent) grid:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-body table-responsive">
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Track24.Billing.Web.Models.ListClientViewModel>()
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(e => e.ClientName);
            columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<a class='btn btn-primary grid-edit' href='" + @Url.Action("EditClient", "PointOfContact", new { id = "#:ClientID#" }) + "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>Edit</a> <a class='btn btn-primary' data-href='" + @Url.Action("DeleteClient", "PointOfContact", new { id = "#:ClientID#" }) + "' data-toggle='modal' data-target='\\#confirm-delete' href='\\#' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>Delete</a>");

        })
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Model(model => model.Id(e => e.ClientID))
            .PageSize(6)
            .Read(read => read.Action("Client_Read", "PointOfContact"))
        )
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
        .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Template(@<text><a id="btnCreate" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add" href="@Url.Action("CreateClient", "PointOfContact")"><span class="k-icon k-add"></span>Add new Client</a></text>))


)
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 2: I tried passing the link through the Create URL but it gives me an error `Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`

```
.ToolBar(toolBar =>
                        {
                            toolBar.Create();
                            toolBar.Save();
                        })
                                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                        .Model(model =>
                                            {

                                                model.Id(p => p.POC_ClientID);
                                            })
                                .PageSize(10)
                                .Read
                                (
                                read => read.Action("ClientBinding_PointOfContacts", "PointOfContact", new { clientID = "#=ClientID#" })
                                )
                                .Create(create => create.Action("CreatePOC", "PointOfContact", new { pclientID = Model.Id }))
                                )
                                .Pageable()
                                .Sortable()
                                .ToClientTemplate()
```

Comment: You can pass it as parameter in create url. Like ./newcontact/create?clientId=#=ClientID# 
In controller you can get in request parameter

or

You can pass like parameter as path variable

./newcontact/create/#=ClientID#

and in controller your url can map like

/newcontact/create/{ClientID}

Comment: @MohammedFarooq Can you elaborate on this please? Because that is exactly what I am doing, passing it as a parameter in the URL but it does not pick the value of `#=ClientID#`. However, when I hardcode the value to something like `, new { id = "20" }` it works fine

Comment: You are doing it for button. What i suggest is to pass the parameter from createUrl

Comment: @MohammedFarooq can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: Please share your code in jsfiddle i  can modify the same.

Comment: refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/ckcaa8gn/

Here you just see the create url how i am passing the parent grid value as parameter in url

Comment: @MohammedFarooq I have edited the question to include code for the parent grid. In the link you shared, you are creating a javascript function create the subgrid?Can we pass the parameter into the kendo script for the sub grid?

Comment: Yes you can pass parameter in create link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66656/discussion-between-sarah-and-mohammed-farooq).

Comment: @MohammedFarooq I am lost, can you explain with the kendo script I am using.  I am unable to comprehend your example in `MVC ASP.NET`

Comment: @MohammedFarooq please see `Edit 2` in the question above

Comment: @MohammedFarooq hi, any pointers from `edit 2`?

Comment: How did you define the CreatePOC in controller. There should be a parameter pclientID. If this is the case then simply change new { pclientID = Model.Id } to new { pclientID = "#=ClientID#" }. (in your edit 2). It would be better if you clean up your post by some major editing.